# Create a copy of a file with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I am sorry for the bad heading, but no better came to my mind.

I am creating a program (**vb.net**) with a database. When I build the program the database is already in and the program is working.

If the user of the build, uses and edits the database, the changes are saved. But if I update the program the database will be overwritten and all the changes of the user are gone.

I'm searching for a solution since hours, but I can't find good keywords for searching. So maybe someone can help me.

My idea is to copy the database from the program, which is saved here:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\XB8ZOKH5.AK0\C9NZMRPR.25M
```

to a permanent storage place,  e.g. here:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\program\database.accdb
```

How can I do this with Visual studio?

Comment: The question is what do you really want to achieve? What if you change the structure of the database (alter table, add index, create store procedure...). Do you want to publish such changes?

Comment: I has to be a fix structure, since the user can insert their own data and the programm will read it.

Comment: Are you publishing with ClickOnce?

Comment: I suggest "How to keep old database when deploying new program version?" as a title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  I learned a similar technique, years ago and it has worked well for small projects like yours.

Your installer should only install a "template" version of your database on the hard drive.

When your program starts up, it can try to connect to the "working copy" of the database.  If the user cannot connect to the database, or there is no setting for the "working copy", the program can make a copy of the "template" (`System.IO.File.Copy`) and save a setting, pointing to the "working copy".  Then each time the program is upgraded, your full database will be safe.  Of course, it is also a good idea to have your program make a "backup" of the database (zip) often.